# Finding when a value in a pandas Series crosses multiple threshold values from another Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have two Pandas Series, say `sensor_values` and `thresholds`. `thresholds` are defined in increasing order. How do I identify that in the `sensor_value` series, at what instances do the values cross *any* of the thresholds defined in the other Series `thresholds`?

What I'm trying to do is basically what has been done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291567/6475377) answer, but instead the threshold (called `line` in that answer) would itself be a Series of multiple values. So I want to check against not one single threshold value but multiple of them, since the data is time-varying, and so for my use-case, different thresholds may apply depending upon the range any of the values in `sensor_values` is in.

I tried to come up with this, but it's not detecting all of the values correctly, only some are detected.

```py
threshold_cross = (((sensor_values.rta >= thresholds.any()) & (sensor_values.next_rta < thresholds.any())) | ((sensor_values.next_rta > thresholds.any()) & (sensor_values.rta <= thresholds.any())) | (sensor_values.rta == thresholds.any()))
```

The `sensor_values` Series may be increasing or decreasing in values. Those thresholds for now only apply to the increasing ones. For decreasing values, a different set of thresholds would apply, but anyways that's a thing I should be able to do it myself once I figure out just for one set of threshold values. So for now, one can assume that both `sensor_values` and `thresholds` are monotonically increasing.

Edit: `sensor_values` is a DataFrame, containing two fields `rta` and `next_rta`, with later being the next instance of the `rta` (time shifted by 1 position, as done in the linked answer)

Comment: Can you provide an example and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you could `pd.cut` the sensors values into intervals between thresholds and then compare those thresholds:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sensors = pd.Series([0.1, 1.3, 2.1, 1.7, 2.6, 3.8, 4.1, 5.1, 4.4, 3.2, 1.6, 7.2])
thresholds = pd.Series([2, 5, 7])

bins = pd.concat([pd.Series(-np.inf), thresholds, pd.Series(np.inf)])
binned = pd.cut(sensors, bins)

crossings = binned != binned.shift()
crossings[0] = False # Don't count the first element
```

Output:

```
>>> crossings.tolist()
[False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True]
```

Important Note:

The above becomes problematic if your sensors take the exact value of one of the thresholds (i.e., given that the bins are treated right-closed, depending on the previous interval it may get counted as crossing or not). In that case, you'll have to write additional code to handle that.